# Vector reference issue

Tags: c++, vector

The reason I create another vector temp is because i want to keep the original values. However, after executing the function, the values are still being modified. When i debug i realize they are pointing to the same address location. Why is this so? and how do i correct this?

```
vector<Node*> vertices;
vector<Node*> facility;
...
for (int i = 0; i < facility.size(); i++){
    vector<Node*>temp(vertices);

    calculateAttDist(0, facility[i]->data, temp);

    for (int j = 0; j < vertices.size(); j++){
        if (vertices[j]->type == 1 && i != 0 && vertices[j]->aDist > temp[j]->key){
            vertices[j]->aDist = temp[j]->key;
        }
        else if (vertices[j]->type == 1 && i == 0){
            vertices[j]->aDist = temp[j]->key;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you hold pointers to the elements ... go for `vector<Node>`

Comment: If you copy a `vector<T>`, the elements are copied as they are. In your case, `T` is a pointer, so the pointer values (the addresses that they point at) will be the same in both the original vector and the copy.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using `vector<Node *>` instead of `vector<Node>`?

Comment: "the values are still being modified." Do tell what you observe. "they are pointing to the same address location". Well, you have copied a bunch of pointers. Where do you want them to point, if not to the same locations the originals point?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you can change your design to use `vector<Node>` instead of `vector<Node *>` you will need to do this a bit more manually:

```
vector<Node*> temp;
temp.reserve(vertices.size());
for (Node* node : vertices)
    temp.push_back(new Node(*node));
```

Note that you also need to make sure you free these copies! You might find it a better idea to do the following, which will destroy the copies when `temp` goes out of scope.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> temp;
temp.reserve(vertices.size());
for (Node* node : vertices)
    temp.push_back(std::make_unique<Node>(*node));
```

And, if `Node` is some virtual base class, instead of using the copy constructor like I've shown above, you'll probably want to create some `clone()` method that returns the correct object.

And finally, using the classes `shared_ptr`, `weak_ptr` and `unique_ptr` are really helpful. While they help with automatically releasing memory, almost more importantly, they imply a contract of how the variable should be used.